# Preg Replace Anchor Title Attribute

Tags: php, html, regex, attributes, preg-replace

I have a `title=""` attribute in an anchor that contains HTML. I'm trying to remove the title attribute entirely but for whatever reason the preg replace I'm using will not work. I've tried:

```
$output = preg_replace( '/title=\"(.*?)\"/',  '', $output );
$output = preg_replace( '/\title="(.*?)"/',   '', $output );
$output = preg_replace( '` title="(.+)"`',    '', $output );
```

None of the above works, but I can use something like:

```
$output = str_replace( 'title', 'class', $output );
```

Just to prove that I was able to do something ( and I wasn't uploading the wrong file or something ). Output looks like this:

```
<a href="#" title="<table border=\&quot;0\&quot; width=\&quot;100%\&quot; cellspacing=\&quot;0\&quot; cellpadding=\&quot;0\&quot;>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td colspan=\&quot;2\&quot; align=\&quot;center\&quot; valign=\&quot;top\&quot;></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td valign=\&quot;top\&quot; width=\&quot;50%\&quot;>
            table content
            </td>
            <td valign=\&quot;top\&quot; width=\&quot;50%\&quot;>
            table content
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>">Link Title</a>
```

So what I'm trying to do is filter `$output` and remove the title attribute entirely including everything inside the title attribute. Why will the `preg_replace()` above not work and what are my options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would **not** use a regex to do operations on [x]html, I'd use a html parser instead.

But if you still want to use a regex then you can use a regex like this:

```
title="[\s\S]*?"
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/aQ1nQ5/2)**

[image]

You can have this code:

```
$re = "/title=\"[\\s\\S]*?\"/"; 
$str = "<a href=\"#\" title=\"<table border=\&quot;0\&quot; width=\&quot;100%\&quot; cellspacing=\&quot;0\&quot; cellpadding=\&quot;0\&quot;>\n    <tbody>\n        <tr>\n            <td colspan=\&quot;2\&quot; align=\&quot;center\&quot; valign=\&quot;top\&quot;></td>\n        </tr>\n        <tr>\n            <td valign=\&quot;top\&quot; width=\&quot;50%\&quot;>\n            table content\n            </td>\n            <td valign=\&quot;top\&quot; width=\&quot;50%\&quot;>\n            table content\n            </td>\n        </tr>\n    </tbody>\n</table>\">Link Title</a>"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

**Update:** You can see a clear example about why you shouldn't use regex to parse html in **[Andrei P.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2997488/andrei-p)** comment

Comment: Why wouldn't yo͛ͫu ᵒ  ̢̯̩̯̲̠u͖̦̫̣s̶̫̲̯̺̰̟̼e͎͓̪ ͍̰͙͚̜̀r͜e͈͔g͏̯̪e̢̠̮̠x ̦̫̝t͚͙͔̫̟̠̹o̴ ̢̮̻̳͍p̡̗a̞̞͕̰͕̺͞ͅr͈̥̼̗͇̝s̖͚̭̳e̷͕̘̜͍̘ ̼͍͝h͜t̸̙ml̷̘͎̬̜̞͉?̱͓̘͎̖ ̧̟̭̱I͢s̸̪̰̗ ̝͕̯͔̙͠t̮͟h̤̩̺̱͠e͉̩̬͉̩͜r̟̠e̡͇̭ ̡̻s̘̠ǫ̪̩̼͖̳̺m͎͈e̥͎t̛̫̖h̛̰̬̹͍̼̬i͉n͎̺̯̼g̠̗̤͍ ̬̥̜̗̭͖̯w̡̦̺̦r̛̪͕͚͚̖͔͇o̮͙̣̙͝n͎g̥͕ ̧w̙̗̟̪͖͈i̶̖͔̣̺͓̘̲t̬̪͍̹̙h͇͓̮ ̷̖t̜̪̙͕h̠̗͍a̡̲̟̯̲ṱ̰?̰͖͚

Comment: Maybe it's my computer that's messing up the above comment but same question as @AndreiP. - Why wouldn't you use regex to parse HTML?

Comment: @AndreiP. lol! man, you rock. Thanks for the comment, I'll use exactly that why not

Comment: :S I don't get the joke, seriously, why not?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee [I'**l**l just leav`e` t͗̎̂̀hͥ͊͒͋i̿s̀̏͋͗ ͥ͛̑ͧ̄͆̚her̓͋̄̇ͬͧͧe.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Howdy_McGee, Andrei posted a retorical comment. As you can see in his comment html can mess up the regex engine if you have a text like hims.

Comment: @Fede + AndreiP. - thanks for your help, i'll read that answer.

Comment: @AndreiP. how do you add that format? I'd like learn that to improve my answers related to regex and html

Comment: @Fede I use [this site](http://www.eeemo.net/). And [here's the git](https://gist.github.com/Rnhmjoj/5855334) written in Python. And to answer your question, no, I don't know how to specifically add that format using regex/html. It's a bit beyond my pay grade to dabble into that. I'm a newbie.